# how to convert list of strings to list of guids

Tags: c#

I have following line of code which creates an list of strings.

```
List<string> tstIdss = model.Ids.Where(x => x.Contains(entityId)).Select(x => x.Split('_').First()).ToList();
```

I need to convert it into list of Guids. i.e. `List<Guid> PermissionIds.`

```
model.PermissionIds= Array.ConvertAll(tstIdss , x => Guid.Parse(x));
```

I tried the above way but getting the following error. `model.PermissionIds` is implemented as following in my model class.

```
public List<Guid> PermissionIds { get; set; }
```

**Error 3**

```
>>The type arguments for method 'System.Array.ConvertAll<TInput,TOutput>(TInput[], System.Converter<TInput,TOutput>)' 
    cannot be inferred from the usage. 
    Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.
```

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can use Linq's `Select` and `ToList` methods:

```
model.PermissionIds = tstIdss.Select(Guid.Parse).ToList();
```

Or you can use the `List<T>.ConvertAll` method:

```
model.PermissionIds = tstIdss.ConvertAll(Guid.Parse);
```

Comment: ooh right, I really don't need the lambda expression, duh.

Comment: @Thomas Levesque, one more very quick confirmation, I have "string entityId = entity"; How i can  convert 'entityId' to Guid in this case.? please

Comment: I got it, it must be like "new Guid(entityId)". Correct me if i am wrong please

Comment: @immirza, yes, you can do that. You can also use `Guid.Parse(entityId)`

Comment: If you want to do the opposite, you can pass it in like this
`var guidStringList = guidList.ConvertAll(g => g.ToString());`

Answer (score 10):

> I have following line of code which creates an list of strings.
>   I need to convert it into list of Guids.

If your list of strings is safe to parse as Guids, I recommend the answer from @Thomas Leveque.

If your list of strings may contain some non-guids, it is safer to use a TryParse as follows:

```
Guid bucket = Guid.Empty;
model.PermissionIds = tstIdss.Where(x => Guid.TryParse(x, out bucket)).Select(x => bucket).ToList();
```

The Where clause will filter out any string which can't be formatted as a Guid.

Answer (score 8):

I'm not familiar with `ConvertAll`, but try using `Select`:

```
model.PermissionIds = tstIdss.Select(s=>Guid.Parse(s)).ToList();
```

Comment: won't it throw an exception?