# I want to check whether items in a list are valid Guids or not. If not valid then replace string with Guid default

Tags: c#, linq, guid

I am getting a list of values which contains Guids and strings. But I need only Guids and have to replace string values with default guid value. Can you please suggest how to do that?

```cs
var Value=abc.where(n=>n.userId).select(n=>n.userId);
```

Thanks

Comment: Please share a [mcve]. I would suspect the answer is going to look like `var result = input.Select(z => (z as Guid?) ?? new Guid()).ToList();` https://dotnetfiddle.net/bNjY7Z

Comment: What type is `userId`? Is it `System.Object` or `System.String`?

Comment: related : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31102320/how-to-convert-list-of-strings-to-list-of-guids, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38331071/convert-a-collection-of-strings-into-collection-of-guid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you have a `List<string>` that you want to transform in a list of Guid.
If this is the case the answer is simply

```
var newList = abc.Select(c => Guid.TryParse(c, out Guid guid) ? guid : default(Guid));
```

If you don't want the invalid guids then

```
var newList = abc.Where(c => Guid.TryParse(c, out _)).Select(x => new Guid(x));
```

Comment: Why not use the out variable from the try parse? `Guid.TryParse(x, out Guid guid)?guid:default(Guid)`

Comment: Perfect it works... I need one more help.. as of now we are adding default value if it's not valid guid but now i don't want to add default value.. i need only Valid Guids...How can we filter this

Comment: @Surya Check out Linq's `Where`.

Comment: @Surya , "_have to replace string values with default guid value._" is in direct contradiction with "_i don't want to add default value.. i need only Valid Guids_". And you should not change requirement to invalidate answer. You should use [ask] and [mre] to have a complete question before hands. I will also recommend using a search engigne with "C# List string to list Guid" and even add the key "site:stackoverflow.com". you will easly find answer like https://stackoverflow.com/a/35027732/6560478. that will cover your new case.